# How to enable both IP and virtual name access in Apache 2.2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am trying to access my server as

http://somedomain.com
http://anotherdomain.com
http://serverip

With NameVirutalHost configuration, the domain names are redirected to their respective folders. But for serverip, I want apache to serve me a different folder. But it is serving me the content for anotherdomain.com. My system is Ubuntu 11.04. How can this issue be solved ?

Comment: Can we get output the virtualhost section of both sites?

Comment: You mean you want the exact configuration options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a `NameVirtualHost` for *serverip* as you would for any other name.  It should also be the first one you define (this will make it the default virtual host if no HTTP `Host:` header is received, as often happens when you point a web browser at an IP address).

Comment: I already tried that. I checked that the browsers send IP address in HOST field and used the IP address for ServerName. But that does not seem to work.

Comment: I added ServerName <serverip> in a VirtualHost directive and it seems to work fine now. Thanks for you suggestion.